# Text-to-speech translator

Tags: java, text-to-speech

I used text to speech translator api in order to convert a text into another language. I added gtranslateapi-1.0.jar and jl-1.0.jar files to library path. This is my code snippet

```
public class NextTranslator {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
        String text = translate.translate("I am programmer", Language.ENGLISH, Language.PORTUGUESE);
        System.out.println(text);
        /*  Translator translate = Translator.getInstance();
         String prefix = translate.detect("I am a bus");
         System.out.println(prefix);*/
    }

}
```

As the output I get the following error

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: translate.google.com.br

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
    at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
    at com.gtranslate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:37)
    at nexttranslator.NextTranslator.main(NextTranslator.java:22)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I can't figure out how to solve this. Thank you in advance

**UPDATED**
After checking the DNS connection following error occured.

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://translate.google.com.br/translate_a/t?client=t&text=I%20am%20programmer&hl=en&sl=en&tl=pt&multires=1&prev=btn&ssel=0&tsel=0&sc=1
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at com.gtranslate.utils.WebUtils.source(WebUtils.java:24)
    at com.gtranslate.parsing.ParseTextTranslate.parse(ParseTextTranslate.java:19)
    at com.gtranslate.Translator.translate(Translator.java:37)
    at nexttranslator.NextTranslator.main(NextTranslator.java:24)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This means I need the apikey as I know. That means Can't I use text-to-speech api without a key?But according to the following link [https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-google-translate-text-to-speech/](http://text-to-speech)
it say that this api is free. Do I have any options to use a text translator for free in my java web application?

Comment: You API apparently needs to connect to translate.google.com.br to work, but your Java program doesn't find the host, which means there's a connectivity problem with your DNS server. Try to ping this host on your development machine.

Comment: I have updated the.Please check the question and help me to find and answer.Thank you in advance

Comment: An 'free' API may require registration.

Comment: Look at it as a service. They give you a 60 day trial: "You sign up for free and get $300 to spend over 60 days on all Google Cloud Platform services."